# Did Jason ever have the pattern of picking his target or was it always random?

Tags: analysis, friday-the-13th

In *Friday The 13th*, does Jason ever have any pattern of picking his targets or is it supposed to be first come first serve?

Sometimes it felt to me that he always targets the people indulging in sex first, as his drowning reason was also someone's ignorance of the kids while being busy with sex. Or I am over-thinking?

Comment: All I can remember is the entire cinema shouting "Answer the damn phone!" ;)

Comment: Of course he targeted people (mostly teens) who indulged in sex.  Don't forget the teens who drank or did drugs.  It's like you don't even know the rules! :P

Comment: I honestly have no idea if this is true, but I always just assumed that Jason preferred killing teenagers who were doing the same things as the counselors were doing when he died. In the first movie, Jason’s mother mentions the counselors being neglectful (drinking and sex?) and that lead to her son drowning. Again, I have no basis other than just a whimsical notion of this, but it’s something I always just assumed to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Jason will stalk and pick off his victims that would 
1. Not alert others to his presence 
2. Seperated from the group, one-two victims at a time with little exceptions

Reasons for survivors making it to the end.
1. Safey in numbers.
2. Aware of things around them

If you look at the films Paramount were responsible for (1-8) you would find this pattern with some deviation.  Examples: Part 6 Tommy was focused and aware of him being alive, the girl that survived was into Tommy so she was with him the whole time.  Part 7 Tina had visions of him and the guy survived by being with her.  Killing them during or after sex is getting them when they are vulnerable.